# How to Prove It, Velleman 4.2.15

Tags: proof-writing, field-theory, proof-explanation

Show that {$1,\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$} is linearly independent over the field of rational numbers.

The following is the solutions:

[image]

I’m confused because this appears to be a proof by cases, but I do not see how these cases are exhaustive. Are there not 8 possible cases to check?

Comment: Here the proof is split according to three cases, which are clearly exhaustive: either $a_3=0$, or $a_2=0$, or neither of those. That was apparently the choice the author of the solution made that gave an effective solution.

Comment: You can list out the 8 Cases & then Check that the 3 Cases given in the Proof covers all the 8 Cases. The Writer has ordered the 8 Cases such that the 3 Cases are sufficient. The Proof is Perfect.